# Inline condition fprintf function

Tags: matlab

At the begining of each of my function I pass a debug flag that is either true or false. I would like to create a function (possibly inline) that uses this flag and prints only if the value is set to true. e.g.:

```
fprintff = @(str) debug&fprintf(str)
...
...
fprintff(str); %will only print if debug is set to true
```

I know I can do it with `fprintff(str,debug)`, but I want to use it without it.

No persistent or global!

Comment: So, without a global or persistent `debug` flag, you want your `fprintff` function to 'know' whether you are debugging, also without passing the `debug` argument to `fprintff`? The only way to do this would be to declare `fprintff` within each function, in which case you only need to change `&` to `&&` and let short circuiting do the work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to define the debug print function to rely on the [short-circuiting](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html) of the `&&` operator. This way `fprintf` is only evaluated when `debug_flag == true` at the moment the function is defined.

```
function foo(bar,debug_flag)
    debug_print = @(varargin) debug_flag && fprintf(1,varargin{:});
    ...
    debug_print('This only prints if debug_flag == true\n');
    ...
end
```